# Placing two venn diagrams on one chart

Tags: r, charts, r-grid, venn-diagram

Using [`VennDiagram`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/index.html) package I'm generating two graphs in the following manner:

```
# First graph
VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(
    area1 = 100,
    area2 = 70,
    cross.area = 30,
    category = c("A1", "B1"),
    fill = c("#00204DFF", "#FFEA46FF")
) -> vg1

# Second graph
VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(
    area1 = 120,
    area2 = 80,
    cross.area = 10,
    category = c("A2", "B2"),
    fill = c("#000004FF", "#FCFFA4FF")
) -> vg2
```

When called via `grid::grid.draw(vg1)` and `grid::grid.draw(vg2)` the charts show as expected:

`grid::grid.draw(vg1)`
[image: vg1]

`grid::grid.draw(vg2)`
[image: vg2]

## Question

How can I create one grid object where both plots are placed one under another?

## Attempt

```
grdFrme <- grid::grid.frame(name = "gf")
grid::grid.pack("gf", vg1)
```

> Error in packGrob(grid.get(gPath), grob, side, row, row.before,
>   row.after,  :    invalid 'grob'

## Desired results

[image: both graphs]

Comment: I believe this is also pretty easy with the `gridExtra` package. At one point, I figured out how to do this in `grid` itself, but it's kind of a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to use awesome [`multipanelfigure`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multipanelfigure/index.html) package (*fill the panels with base, 'lattice', 'ggplot2' and 'ComplexHeatmap' plots, grobs, and PNG, JPEG, SVG and TIFF images*).

```
library(multipanelfigure)
figure <- multi_panel_figure(columns = 1, rows = 2)

figure %<>% 
    fill_panel(vg1) %<>%
    fill_panel(vg2)
```

[image]